# How to reset event without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I have 2 XML views. In the first one is input field and button to navigate to second view.In the second view is table. When I press button in first view I push filter parameter to second view and apply filter with beforeRebindTable. In the second view I have button to navigate back to first view. But when I change value in input field no new query is sent. It just navigate me to the second view.

So my question is, how can I reset, or refresh button event so I can send new query without reloading page ?

This is my event for button in the first view.

```
navToSecond : function (oEvent){
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.setProperty("/First", this.getView().byId("inp").getValue());
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "Filter");
        this.getRouter().navTo("second");
```

Comment: Probably you could call oModel.refresh before navTo?

Comment: Thank you for reply @slkorolev. But I tried it like oModel.refresh(true) but it didnt change anything. No new query is created after changed value in input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your property before you store it as "Filter" Model. So the change event fired to early and get lost. But why you create a new model on each turn?

```
navToSecond : function (oEvent){
    var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel(oModel, "Filter");
    if (!oModel) {
        oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "Filter");
    }
    oModel.setProperty("/First", this.getView().byId("inp").getValue());
    this.getRouter().navTo("second");
    }
```

Comment: Hi Markus  I think the problem is that I use on second view onBeforeRebindTable method where I call global model and then push filter. So there is maybe another approach to solve this, I really don't know I'm beginner.

Comment: Hi,
maybe. You should bind the controls only one time. All updates will be automaticly triggerd by events in the background. Rebinding is not necessary.
To activate the new filter I would bind a change listener on model path "/First" that will be called on each change.
`var binding = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONPropertyBinding(oModel, '/First');
   binding.attachChange(function() {'update filter in table binding});`

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the code where you fill your model with data?

You need to perform this function again. It does not have to be before your navigation event, as the data bindings will update automatically. The following should work:

```
    navToSecond : function (oEvent){

    var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("Filter");
    if (oModel ){
    jQuery.ajax( {
        url: "my/data/url",
        success: function(data,status,jxXHR){
//this is an example with an AJAX call, but the point is loading new json data into your model
    oModel.setData(data);
    },
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      });
    } else {
      oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
      sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "Filter");
      oModel.setProperty("/First", this.getView().byId("inp").getValue());
    }
            this.getRouter().navTo("second"); 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, Im new into this. But I think I fill value of model when I set property oModel.setProperty("/First", this.getView().byId("inp").getValue()); then in the second view controller in method beforeRebindTable I called model and property  var myObject = sap.ui.getCore().getModel('Filter').getProperty('/First'); and put it into filter oBindingParams.filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter('Status', 'EQ', myObject ));

Comment: It looks like your code generate new URL second time but I think I need to edit this line url: "my/data/url", but Im not sure.

Comment: @M.Mikuš please log the value of "this.getView().byId("inp").getValue()", and check if it contains the information that you expect. Furthermore, make sure that you do use the line "sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "Filter");" a second time, or you might 'unset' the model from the core. You can check this by logging your view, and checking the models/propagated properties. If you provide this information I can help you further